# Google Client Api - auto auth

Tags: google-analytics-api

I want to show Google Analytics data from my GA Acoount and makes it available for any user without authentication.
I have OAuth2 access done, but I have to every time login to my google account. is there any way how to set autoauth? I mean  that every user whose open the page get data from my Google Analytics pages. I need something like GAPI class. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Questions:**

1.What have you tried?

2.Whats the point of showing your analytics details to all the users?

**You can try the following:**

1. You have to store your oauth token in db or in some files.
2. When you are loading the page , you have to check in the backend its a valid token , or expired token. If its expired you can exchange the token with the valid oauth token .
3. Once you got the valid token you can call the api on the fly and display the Google Analytics data to user.

Comment: 1. I have tried GAPI, but it is a little bit old
2. I want to show our statistics to clients

Ok, but I need stable token, it means it shouldn't expire. The data should be avaiable all of the time. Thanks.